# Как сравнить две длины массива?

Tags: javascript

Как сравнить две длины массива и выполнить функцию?

Есть два массива, если в двух массивах длина больше одного то выполняется функция, если в каком то из них длина становится ровна 0, остановить запущенную !!!

Как данное можно сделать?

```
function start() {
document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML = '<div>Длина двух массивов больше 0</div>'

  //Функция запуска
}

function stop() {
     document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML = '<div>Какойто из массивов равен 0</div>'
  // Остановить  запущенную функцию если какой-то из счетчиков стал равен "0" 
  //и ждать изменения если оба счётчика станут равны больше "0" 
}

function liki() {
  const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll('#user uidm')].map(uidm => uidm.attributes.uid.value);
  if (ids.length > 0) {}
  const idss = [...document.querySelectorAll('#user uid')].map(uid => uid.attributes.uid.value);
  if (idss.length > 0) {}
}
```

Comment: Как понять `остановить запущенную`?

Comment: Если откровенно, то не совсем понятно, что именно ты хочешь реализовать. Может кто другой поймет

Comment: При каком событии это будет происходить? Опиши вопрос подробнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, что верно понял вопрос автора, но на уровне интуиции, думаю решение такое...

```
function start() {
  document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML = '<div>Длина двух массивов больше 0</div>'

  //Функция запуска
}

function stop() {
  document.getElementById('ok').innerHTML = '<div>Какойто из массивов равен 0</div>'
  // Остановить  запущенную функцию если какой-то из счетчиков стал равен "0" 
  //и ждать изменения если оба счётчика станут равны больше "0" 
}

function liki() {
  const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll('#user uidm')].map(uidm => uidm.attributes.uid.value);
  const idss = [...document.querySelectorAll('#user uid')].map(uid => uid.attributes.uid.value);
  if (idss.length > 0 && ids.length > 0) {
    stop();
  } else {
    start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Да!!! да!!! сравнение все верно работает спасибо!!! Только надо что бы проверялось изменилось ли состояние одного из массивов или нет!!!! Объясню кратко там игра на 4 пользователя с одной стороны два игрока и с другой!!! Если с двух сторон по одному то игра запускается!!! Если с какойто стороны ноль игроков игра останавливается!!! Если кто то зашел то снова запускается!!! Как то надо что бы в цикле это все было!!! Вот для чего это сравнение!!!

Comment: Ну на сколько я понял, тебе надо на стороне сервера, проверять, зашел кто в игру или нет. Вопрос очень общий...

Answer (score 1):

Решение данного вопроса

```
function liki() {
const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll('#user uidm')].map(uidm => uidm.attributes.uid.value);
const idss = [...document.querySelectorAll('#user uid')].map(uid => uid.attributes.uid.value);
if (ids.length > 0 && idss.length > 0) {
    status = 'on'
}else {
    status ='off'
}
if(status==='on') {
    start();
  }
 }
    setInterval(liki,100);
    let timer = 1000;
    let timenull = null;
    function start() {
            if (!timenull) {
            console.log('запущенно')
        }
        clearTimeout(timenull);
        timenull = setTimeout(stop, timer);
      }
        function stop() {
        timenull = null;
      console.log('Не запущенно');
     }
```